# Drag and drop the imageview -- android

Tags: android, performance

I'm pretty new to this topic. I have different image view which should do drag and drop functions. I done the below code

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    layoutParams.setMargins((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY(), 0, 0);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

when i used above code, the image is not dragging properly. Can anyone pls guide me on where i made mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Like I hope it will help to u... [Link](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/)